# Is it possible to override <strong> properties within a CSS class only?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div that contains three words, and I want one of the words in the div to be emphasized in a different font and size. Is it possible to override the default `<strong>` in that div's class so that I can just use, for example, `hello there <strong> world` for the word "world" to be emphasized differently to the other "strong-ed" words that aren't in the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to ad in which container you are. So you can still use `<strong>` element elsewhere.

```
<div id="container">
  hello there <strong> world </strong>
</div>

#container strong
{
font-weight: normal;
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set styles to `strong` tags:

```
strong{
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

Use another selector before `strong` to apply it to `strong` tags inside certain tags.

Comment: But wouldn't this affect the other words that have the strong tag that aren't in the div?

Comment: Of course. In that case put the div's css selector before strong.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing it from strong to the inline element `<span>`.  This will give you all the control you need.

```
<div id="myid">hello there <span>world</span></div>

#myid span {properties:values}
```